# Java dependency injection and targeted builds

Tags: java, maven, dependency-injection, build, dagger-2

I'm currently working on a Java 8 project (no big frameworks allowed, quite similar context to Android apps, just slimmed down for use in embedded context), which is very inflexible with respect to targeted builds. Thus I'm generally exploring the possibility to bind different implementations via dependency injection on compile time for different build environments.

Probably the simplest example would be to have two implementations of the same class, one related to say test environment with debug logging and the other for production environment without it, where via dependency injection (preferrably with Dagger 2) I could build the project injecting either one implementation or the other automatically, with respect to the build environment.

The idea is to have clean production code and still be able to fetch a let's say child implementation so the testers/devs can see debug logging when needed and just inject for example the parent / another implementation of the same interface (without debugging code), when compiling the code for production. This would allow us to share the same code base and still not pollute production code with irrelevant code, which would only decrese performance on run time and increases application size and code complexity in general. I'm currently in the scope of Dagger 2, Java 8 SE & a multi-project/-module maven build (could potentially be moved to a Gradle project, but would like to minimize the changes if possible).

I was wondering:

- Is the general solution idea good & are there better ways to do it?
- Can this be achieved via JSR-330 (javax.inject) annotations / Dagger 2 and possibly java.lang.annotation.ElementType or custom / named / scoped annotations? Is there a better way to do it?
- If possible - how can I relate the different build targets, defined in the maven poms to the annotations in our java classes and ultimately use Dagger 2 to inject the correct class on compile time, based on the current environment settings and the annotations in parent and child implementations?

Big thanks to all in advance, hope the answer will help others, since I guess this should be a common issue when dealing with big projects where one wants to have as clean and performance friendly code in their compiled production applications as possible.

Comment: This sounds like a bad idea. You would have to keep multiple files up to date (production and testing with logs). It would be way better to use a Logging mechanism that you can turn off for production builds

Comment: Logging was just an example. What I would like is to have clean code in a file for production use and potentially extend it in a child, where all dirty and useless things for testing/dev purposes happen, but distinguish the 2 (in the case the assumption was via annotations) in some way, so I can tell my DI framework which one to take, depending on the build settings. And I don't have to touch a lot of files at all, just adjust the implementation for testing with a new for example log entry, if a tester wants to see some extra information, but leave the production code free of boiler plate code